# swift 3, PHFetchResult.enumerateObjects error

Tags: swift3

In swift 3,the method is show me "ambiguous use of 'enumerateObjects'",what happen.how can i do?

```
extension PHFetchResult {
public func assetCollection() -> [PHAssetCollection] {
    var list :[PHAssetCollection] = []
    self.enumerateObjects { (object, index, stop) in
        if object is PHAssetCollection {
            let collection = object as! PHAssetCollection
            list.append(collection)
        }
    }
    return list
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this noh. You can't directly add extension for `PHFetchResult` because it has other ObjectType as its generic parameter `PHFetchResult<ObjectType>` . So you must do something else.

```
class FetchPhoto {

    class func assetCollection() -> [PHAssetCollection] {
        var list :[PHAssetCollection] = []

        PHAssetCollection.fetchMoments(with: nil).enumerateObjects(EnumerationOptions.concurrent) { (collection, _, _) in
                list.append(collection)
        }

        return list
    }
}
```

`PHAssetCollection.fetchMoments` returns `PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection>` here `PHAssetCollection` is the `ObjectType` for the `PHFetchResult`. You got the ambiguous error because you have not specified the objectType.

A generic way to approach this.

```
 class FetchPhoto {

    class func assetCollection<T : PHObject>(result : PHFetchResult<T>) -> [T] {

        var list : [T] = []

        result.enumerateObjects(EnumerationOptions.concurrent) { (object, _, _) in
            list.append(object)
        }

        return list
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
    class PhotosHelper {

        class func fetchAllLocalIdentifiersOfPhotos(completion : (_ localIdentifiers : [String]) -> ()) {

            let photos : PHFetchResult<PHAsset> = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil)
            photos.enumerateObjects ({ _,_,_ in

// Do your operations, you can see that there is no warnings/errors in this one
            })

        }
    }
```

Comment: why add (EnumerationOptions.concurrent) to trail of fun

Comment: I can't get this to work. When I try to add enumeration options I get "Argument labels '(_:,_:) do not match any available overloads", but when I remove the options its still showing as ambiguous use..

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 3.0**: Just add the **Round Brackets** before Curly Brackets starts after enumerateObjects.

```
extension PHFetchResult {
  public func assetCollection() -> [PHAssetCollection] {
    var list :[PHAssetCollection] = []
    self.enumerateObjects ({ (object, index, stop) in
        if object is PHAssetCollection {
            let collection = object as! PHAssetCollection
            list.append(collection)
        }
    })
    return list
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and it worked; would you mind explaining why? Seems like a change that shouldn't do anything

Comment: This is all very well, but it is ridiculous that PHFetchResult should adopt NSFastEnumeration in Objective-C and yet we cannot use `for...in` with it in Swift.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a lot of time.